# CSS :not selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to use the CSS3 `:not` selector. Basically, I have a table that when you hover a row, the background color changes:

```
.table-hover tbody tr:hover > td, .table-hover tbody tr:hover > th {
    background-color: #272727;
}
```

On one of the `<tr>`'s I apply a `latest-review` class to the row. When I hover over the`latest-review` row, the background color still changes because of the above CSS. I'd like it not to change colors. I've tried this and failed:

```
.table-hover tbody tr:hover > td:not(.latest-review), .table-hover tbody tr:hover > th:not(.latest-review) {
    background-color: #272727;
}
```

I am not really sure what else to try at this point. I am using Chrome currently and I am not worried about the `:not` selector not being supported in older browsers.

Comment: Why don't you try inverting the logic - apply a class .not-latest-review to everything which will allow the highlight, then remove that class when you don't want the highlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you write that `.latest-review` is applied to `<tr>`, but your code snippet uses `<td>` and `<th>`. Either way, it's easier imho to simply add a simpler second rule after your hover rule (and not use `:not`):

```
.table-hover tr:hover {
    background-color: #272727;
}

.table-hover .latest-review {
    background-color: %original_color%
}
```

Comment: I prefer this over using `:not()` since it works in all browsers.

Comment: I would have done it this way. The thing is I am using Twitter Bootstrap as my base CSS. Sort of the first project I've used it on and I've found it difficult to override certain things unless named exactly how bootstrap labels them. I removed the bootstrap version of table hover and I am using this method instead, thanks

Comment: @Ronnie: You can always override a CSS declaration by being more specific. This means that you could simply write `.table-hover tbody tr.latest-review:hover > td, .table-hover tbody tr.lateste-review:hover > th` to ensure it gets overriden. I'd do that instead of altering the defaults.

Answer (score 0):

The first CSS rule overrides the second. Either remove the first one or reset the color:

```
.table-hover tbody tr:hover > td.latest-review, .table-hover tbody tr:hover > th.latest-review {
    background-color: default-color;
}
```